# Software PDR - how to explain the code by PDR ( preliminary design review) with clock/diagram

Tags: uml, visio

I am trying to write PDR for the first time.

I have the follwoing important blocks/parts which I want to demonstrate in the PDR by blocks or diagarm (e.g UML).

1. A job's queue which I add a new job (estimation job).
2. The job "contains" a function (device_estimation) which call another function (send_msg). Bothe functions belongs to the same class.

How should I descript those three parts (the job, and the 2 functions) by special blocks / diagram?

p.s 
I use Visio

Comment: Would you mind to explain what PDR means? I guess it's not Photodissociation region

Comment: @Thomas Kilian-The purpose of the preliminary design review is to let the TAs and instructor get an idea of what your project is, how it will function, and what approach you will take with your design. Design reviews are not meant to be busy work, in industry they are used to identify critical functions, features, and faults and are not taken lightly.

Comment: You should use the edit link above to update your question.

Comment: Maybe you should start by re-reading your question and making it consistent and fix the obvious typo's. Do you mean *b*locks or *c*locks, or both? And what do they have to do with diagrams?

Comment: @Thomas Kilian- according your diagram it seems that device_estimation(), and send_msg belong to a class name job (but they don't.....the belong to another class)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sequence diagram in this case.

[image]

It's easy to show call structures like in your case.

Comment: -according your diagram it seems that device_estimation(), and send_msg belong to a class name job (but they don't.....the belong to another class)

Comment: Well, your description is a bit wishy washy, so you should take this as example, not as solution.